# Apache htaccess force out of www. EXCEPT a specific domain

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have several sites that all run off of this sames rule to remove www:

```
# remove www from host
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}s/%1 ^(on(s)|offs)/(.+)
RewriteRule ^ http%2://%3%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

This works fine but I want a way to add exceptions, so I thought I could make a rule right under that like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.exceptiondomain\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.exceptiondomain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But it isn't working.. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your current rules will create a rewrite loop... remove `www`, add `www`, repeat...

You need to include the exception (an additional `RewriteCond` directive) in your first rule block and only remove `www` if the domain is not one of those you are creating an exception for. For example:

```
# remove www from host
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=www.exceptiondomain.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/server-status
# etc...
```